# JasperSoft ReportServer - Visualize.js integration issues

Tags: jasperserver, visualize

I am testing out the visualize.js integration from jasper reportserver pro edition. It does not work because my application also has its jquery/require modules and visualize.js also tries to load it's own version of jquery/require modules. The overwriting of my frameworks libraries creates many uncertain and unpredictable issues.

Is there a way to tell jaspersoft to not load jquery/require libraries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the jQuery.noConflict() to handle multiple versions of it on the same page. See [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

Comment: how should I handle the require.js conflict? The require.config.js from those 2 applications overwrite each other and then I run into Module not found errors at random.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is too late now, but in the past we faced with the similar issues, and the solution was to insert this before your script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

And afterwards in your script, change all $ to the j$
That is what solved our problem with multiple jQuery libraries on the same page. Hope it helps you too.